# Angular does not insert before and after pseudo elements when inserting dynamic component

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 11 app.
In this app I am building a organisational tree based upon OL elements in different levels.
I am drawing the node lines using the ::before and ::after pseudo elements in CSS.

The problem is that I am using a node component inside the main three component to draw the OL elements and doing this the browser displays no ::before and ::after elements (but the tree is displayed) to hook into.

It all works fine if I just use a static OL tree but not dynamically. So my question is, can I force Angular to add the before and after elements somehow?

**My TreeOrgChart component**

```
<ol class="component-orgchart" *ngFor="let item of collection">
  <li>
    <div class="node-title">
      {{item.label}}
    </div>
    <app-tree-orgchart-node [model]="item" [mode]="mode"></app-tree-orgchart-node>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**My TreeOrgchartNode component**

```
<ol *ngIf="model.children.length > 0">
  <li (click)="routerNode(node)" *ngFor="let node of model.children">
    <div class="node-title">
      {{node.label | capitalize}}
    </div>
    <app-tree-orgchart-node [model]="node" [mode]="mode"></app-tree-orgchart-node>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Did you set the content of the pseudo elements in the css? like content: ""

Comment: Yes, strange thing is the same CSS code works fine with static OL list but not when using recursing angular components.

Comment: Well.. then im out of ideas too

Comment: @MarkDenn what is your use-case ? and what are you trying to do ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b8kews?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomments%2Fcomments.component.html @MarkDenn. Take this example and edit css in this example and share link, and show your demo here. It would be helpful too.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I am trying to build an organisational chart using Angular, CSS and OL elements.

Comment: @MarkDenn in above stackblitz link add your own css and re share link and show demo here so that it would be helpful to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b8kews?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomments%2Fcomments.component.html